# not to include asp.net identity tables in database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

Hello I have enabled automatic migrations with code first in my asp.net mvc project : `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`. 
I do not want to have the identity tables (user, roles, user roles, etc..) created by default in my .net application. How can I prevent them to be created?

I tried to delete the database from Sql server management Studio and re-create my db using update-database -force, but the tables are still there.

**update**

I created a migration that deletes the tables, but I would prefer not to have to solve my problem like this

```
 DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers"); 
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers"); 
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers"); 
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles"); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" }); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" }); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex"); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" }); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" }); 
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex"); 
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins"); 
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims"); 
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers"); 
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles"); 
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `ApplicationDbContext` probably inherited from `IdentityDbContext`, you must change that to inherit from `DbContext`.

Change this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{ 
}
```

to this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your goal is (no Identity, separate Identity context as Kahbazi suggests, etc.) But since you worded it that you don't want the tables created by default and you just recently enabled migrations, then you probably just need to create an initial, baseline migration that takes a snapshot of your current database, but includes no code. Then your next migration will only be the things you add or change:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration MyInitialBaseline -IgnoreChanges
update-database
```

The `-IgnoreChanges` tells EF to just do the model snapshot and not re-create existing objects. Without this initial migration, EF will compare your first migration to an empty model and re-create everything including the Identity tables. Now you can work with your model and generate subsequent migrations as needed:

```
add-migration AddFoo
update-database
```

[Migrations under the hood](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood)